# twitter bootstrap-sass button hover issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my gemfile:

```
gem "less-rails", "~> 2.1.2"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', "~> 1.4.3"
gem "less-rails-bootstrap", "~> 1.4.2"
```

A standard button btn class shows a very ugly shadow on hovering effect whereas other buttons urgent and info work nicely.

I also found other issues while trying to use the top-bar, the dropdown navigation won't work.

I must be missing something, any idea how to debug this?

Am I missing a Gem?

Comment: You seem to be using both my bootstrap-sass library *and* the less-rails-bootstrap library. This is almost certainly unneeded, but without any additional hints as to what you're doing (stylesheet imports or button code) there's not a lot I can suggest.

Comment: removed the less libraries and commented out some of the default scaffolds SCSS and the issue is gone! Formulating the problem + your hint helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Thomas, BTW I suppose you must already be working on 2.0 release ... do you have a pre-release I could try? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed unnecessary Less gems and commented out some scaffolds code: a{} ...